# Ubuntu on Thinkpad E560

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, hibernate

I installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on my Lenovo Thinkpad E560 and as a begginer user of Ubuntu everything worked nice... But then it went into hibernate and my laptop went freezed. I had to restart the BIOS and lots of things I don´t understand, but finally I was able to bring it back to life.
I´ve been reading the Forum and discovered that´s something quite common with Lenovo users... but all posts were quite old, from some years ago.

Any suggestion before just reinstalling the lastest release of Ubuntu?.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

My computer is also ThinkPad, and when I press hibernate mode, the same situation as you appear. So I simply set the laptop to close the lid and the computer still runs in the background. So I use Lock mode every time and use Xscreensaver. Although my answer can't help you, this is just my usual practice.